# Laravel Application Response Time Slow on Kubernetes vs VM

Tags: php, node.js, kubernetes, nginx, laravel-artisan

## SOS

I have Laravel web app which is running on Kubernetes
But some request taking long time and getting error `net::ERR_FAILED 504 (Gateway Time-out) ????

I tested same web app on `VM-ubuntu` (not in K8s/not in docker)  there is no such issue, all requests responsing very fast and no error `504`

API's itself working very fast when we check via `curl`

So far

I tried to scale up pod of webapp to `20` - no result

I tried get to webapp via `IP` (NodePort) - no result

I tried to run on new K8s cluster - no result
But still same error:

### Is this Laravel issue or Kubernetes conf??

[image]

Can you please give an idea

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y wget sudo
RUN apt install -y lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common gnupg2
RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sury-php.list
RUN wget -qO - https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt update

RUN apt-get install -y php8.1 php8.1-fpm php8.1-mbstring php8.1-zip php8.1-xml php8.1-mysql php8.1-curl \
    php8.1-gd php8.1-redis php8.1-soap nginx supervisor nano zip unzip mc

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
#RUN mkdir /run/php

RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
COPY ./server/docker-configs/nginxconf/netcore.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/netcore.conf
COPY . /usr/src/app/
COPY ./server/docker-configs/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx_php.conf
#COPY .env.example .env
EXPOSE 8080

RUN sed -i 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 50M/' /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 50M/' /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 2048M/' /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/;clear_env = no/clear_env = no/' /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

#RUN chown www-data:www-data -R /usr/src/app/storage/

RUN php --ini

RUN cd /usr/src/app/ && composer install

RUN composer install
CMD ["sh", "/usr/src/app/server/docker-configs/init.sh"]

#FRONTEND
RUN apt-get install -y npm curl
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt install -y nodejs
#COPY .env.example .env
RUN cd /usr/src/app/frontend/ && cp .env.example .env && npm install && npm run build
```

`deploy.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: call-center-netcore-configmap
  namespace: develop
data:
  use-http2: "false"
  APP_NAME: "call-center.xyzcomp.com"
  APP_ENV: "production"
  APP_DEBUG: "true"
  APP_URL: "https://call-center.xyzcomp.com"

  LOG_CHANNEL: "stack"
  LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL: "null"
  LOG_LEVEL: "debug"

  DB_CONNECTION: "mysql"
  DB_HOST: "cluster1-haproxy.pxc.svc.k8s.xyzcompany.net"
  DB_PORT: "3306"
  DB_DATABASE: "netcore-call-center"

  BROADCAST_DRIVER: "log"
  CACHE_DRIVER: "file"
  FILESYSTEM_DRIVER: "local"
  QUEUE_CONNECTION: "sync"
  SESSION_DRIVER: "database"
  SESSION_LIFETIME: "120"

  MEMCACHED_HOST: "127.0.0.1"

  REDIS_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
  REDIS_PASSWORD: "null"
  REDIS_PORT: "6379"

  MAIL_MAILER: "smtp"
  MAIL_HOST: "mailhog"
  MAIL_PORT: "1025"
  MAIL_USERNAME: "null"
  MAIL_PASSWORD: "null"
  MAIL_ENCRYPTION: "null"
  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: "null"
  MAIL_FROM_NAME: "${APP_NAME}"

  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ""
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ""
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "us-east-1"
  AWS_BUCKET: ""
  AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT: "false"

  PUSHER_APP_ID: ""
  PUSHER_APP_KEY: ""
  PUSHER_APP_SECRET: ""
  PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: "mt1"

  VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY: "${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
  VITE_PUSHER_HOST: "${PUSHER_HOST}"
  VITE_PUSHER_PORT: "${PUSHER_PORT}"
  VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME: "${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
  VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: "${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

  MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY: "${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
  MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER: "${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

  NETCORE_API_URL: "https://api.xyzcomp.com"
  NETCORE_NOTIFICATION_URL: "https://notification.xyzcomp.com"
  NETCORE_NOMENCLATURE_URL: "https://nomenclature.xyzcomp.com"

  NETCORE_API_TOKEN: ""
  NETCORE_NOMENCLATURE_API_TOKEN: ""
  NETCORE_NOTIFICATION_API_TOKEN: ""


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: call-center-netcore-deploy
  namespace: develop
  labels:
    app: call-center-netcore
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: call-center-netcore
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: call-center-netcore
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: call-center-netcore
        image: docker-c2.xyzcompany.net/call-center-netcore/call-center-netcore-kz:v0.BUILDVERSION
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: call-center-netcore-secrets
        - configMapRef:
            name: call-center-netcore-configmap
        volumeMounts:
          - name: pvc-call-center-netcore-kz
            mountPath: /usr/src/app/storage/
      #imagePullSecrets:
      #- name: regcred
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: drokh-jenkins
      volumes:
        - name: pvc-call-center-netcore-kz
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: call-center-netcore-kz-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: call-center-netcore-service
  namespace: develop
spec:
  selector:
    app: call-center-netcore
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: call-center-netcore-ingress
  namespace: develop
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "5m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "360"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "360"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "call-center.xyzcomp.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: call-center-netcore-service
            port:
              number: 8080
  - host: "www.call-center.xyzcomp.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: call-center-netcore-service
            port:
              number: 8080
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: call-center-cron
  namespace: develop
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: drokh-jenkins
          containers:
            - name: call-center-cronjob
              image: docker-c2.xyzcompany.net/call-center-netcore/call-center-netcore-kz:v0.BUILDVERSION
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              envFrom:
                - secretRef:
                    name: call-center-netcore-secrets
                - configMapRef:
                    name: call-center-netcore-configmap
              command:
                - php
              args:
                - artisan
                - schedule:run
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

`VM ubuntu Nginx config`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/call-center.xyzcomp.com;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/sc_access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/sc_error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/call-center.xyzcomp.com/frontend/dist/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/call-center.xyzcomp.com/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /storage {
        root /var/www/call-center.xyzcomp.com/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/call-center.xyzcomp.com/public;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

`Project files`

[image]

folder `frontend`

[image]

Comment: Have you done more detailed profiling to understand where the time is actually going?  (Are the Nginx latency and backend latency significantly different?  Lost time in database I/O?)  It seems likely that just the Kubernetes manifest isn't going to be enough to debug this, but a [mcve] is necessarily going to follow from the research you've done.  There's already a lot of information here, so avoid including unnecessary ConfigMap variables, CronJobs, and other things secondary to the actual problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Additionaly, service not evrytime returing `504` it's random, while it's waitng response in backend server no logs in Nginx. Btw, Thanks for your recommedation. I'll make correction to my question

Comment: @DavidMaze, last but not least - mostly `504` happening when we refresh web page too fast and when we swtich between pages

Comment: Usually has to do with the kind of mount your are using for your application. Share your yml file so we can help you better diagnose this.

Comment: @prog_24 you can check deploy.yaml which I shared. 

Let me explain idea of project
`Dockerfile` builds laravel image and nodejs app in single image

The guy who wrote before `Dockerfile` has lack of knowledge.
The Dockerfile simulates same actions as manual running of laravel and nodejs there is just `run` commands 
from `Dockerfile` you can undestand how project was build 

But image works. 
Any idea about this point?

Comment: @prog_24 I also shared file tree image for better understanding for you

Comment: @prog_24 If you have experience on deploying Laravel and nodejs fronted on Kubernetes plz share with your approach